Show $\mathbb{P}(A_n \ge B_n | \mathcal{I}) \le e^{-t}$ is equivalent with $\mathbb{P}(A_n \ge B_n) \le e^{-t}$.
I'm working with concentration inequalities such as Bernstein inequality and my work also involves cross fitting. Currently, the inequality holds conditional on $\mathcal{I}$, which is a set of independent training samples. In the following, I will simplify the notation while keeping the gist of my confusion.
Suppose I have the following concentration inequality:
$$\mathbb{P}(A_n \ge B_n | \mathcal{I}) \le e^{-t}.$$
This can be interpreted as $\forall t\ge 0$, there exists $n$ such that the above inequality holds.
The sequence of random variable $A_n$ has randomness comes from $\mathcal{I}$ and something else. The sequence $B_n$ is also random, but when conditional on $\mathcal{I}$, it is fixed or can be considered as a sequence of real numbers.
I want to show the above inequality is equivalent with the following one which is without the conditional:
$$\mathbb{P}[A_n \ge B_n]  \le e^{-t}$$
Here is my proof:
Notice $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(A_n \ge B_n) | \mathcal{I}] = \mathbb{P}(A_n \ge B_n | \mathcal{I}) \le e^{-t}$, we can integrate out both sides with respect to the distribution of $\mathcal{I}$, or equivalently, take expectation on both sides with respect to $\mathcal{I}$, get
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(A_n \ge B_n) | \mathcal{I}]]  \le \mathbb{E}[e^{-t}]=e^{-t}.$$
By tower property, the LHS becomes $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}(A_n \ge B_n)]$, which is $\mathbb{P}[A_n \ge B_n]$. Therefore, we have
$$\mathbb{P}[A_n \ge B_n]\le e^{-t}.$$

I'm not sure I believe this. There's not enough specific context and $p(A>B|F)\neq p(A>B)$ for general events $F$, that's for sure

Wait, also if this holds for all $t$ then the probability is just... zero. There's definitely something missing

@FShrike Thank you for pointing out. I have updated the question.

I am also unclear about $\mathcal I$.  If $\mathbb{P}(A_n \ge B_n | \mathcal{I}) \le e^{-t}$ is true for given $n$ and $t$ and for all possible $\mathcal I$ then $\mathbb{P}(A_n \ge B_n | \mathcal{I}) \le e^{-t}$ should also be true

@Henry Thanks for the comment! Indeed that is my intuition. We can view $\mathcal{I}$ as a separate training dataset which is independent from other randomness in $A_n$. I just want to write this argument formally by translating the probability into expectation and then using tower property.
